# How to retrieve dynamic value from Django settings.py in a Celery Task?

Tags: django, celery, systemd

My Django rely on Celery and Celerybeat to spawn tasks. I have 3 systemd services/units:

1. myapp.service (gunicorn daemon)
2. celery-myapp.service (celery worker(s))
3. celerybeat-myapp.service (celerybeat daemon)

I have an environment variable MY_SECRET defined in my main "myapp.service" service (systemd unit).

I can't get this value from settings.py or directly environment variable in my tasks (tasks.py), but I can retrieve this value smoothly from my view (views.py) using settings.py or environment variable directly.

Do I need to replicate environment variable MY_SECRET defined in myapp.service to celery-myapp.service and celerybeat-myapp.service so that I could grab this value from my Celery tasks? How can I retrieve MY_SECRET value i, my Celery task?

**myapp.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=My App
After=network.target
Wants=celery-myapp.service
Wants=celerybeat-myapp.service

[Service]
User=myapp
Group=nginx
Environment=MY_SECRET=1234
WorkingDirectory=/opt/myproject/
ExecStart=/opt/myproject/env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --log-level debug --bind unix://opt/myproject/myapp.sock myaproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Environment variable is referenced in my Django project 'settings.py' along with other settings I intended to use within the application:

**settings.py**

```
# Populated with environment variable defined by systemd unit
MY_SECRET = os.environ.get('MY_SECRET')
# Static value
MY_URL= 'http://127.0.0.1'
```

From my view I can get value defined as environment variable MY_SECRET from settings.py and directly from environment:

**views.py**

```
def my_view(request):
    from django.conf import settings as project_settings

    my_secret_env = os.environ.get('MY_SECRET')
    my_secret_setting = project_settings.MY_SECRET
    my_url_setting = project_settings.MY_URL

   return render(request,'mypage.html',{
       'my_secret_env': my_secret_env,
       'my_secret_setting': my_secret_setting,
       'my_url_setting': my_url_setting,
   )
```

**mypage.html**

```
    {% block page_content %}
    <!-- Value displayed properly -->
    <p><strong>my_secret_env:</strong> {{ my_secret_env }}</p>
    <!-- Value displayed properly -->
    <p><strong>my_secret_setting:</strong> {{ my_secret_setting }}</p>
    <!-- Value displayed properly -->
    <p><strong>my_url_setting:</strong> {{ my_url_setting }}</p>
    {% endblock %}
```

From my task I can't get value defined as environment variable MY_SECRET from settings.py nor directly from environment.

On the other hand, static value from settings.py is properly retrieved:

**tasks.py**

```
@shared_task
def task_mytask():
    from django.conf import settings as project_settings

    my_secret_env = os.environ.get('MY_SECRET')
    my_secret_setting = project_settings.MY_SECRET
    my_url_setting = project_settings.MY_URL

    # No value displayed
    print(my_secret_env)
    # No value displayed
    print(my_secret_setting)
    # Value displayed properly
    print(my_url_setting)

@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=60))
def task_myperiodictask():
    task_mytask.delay()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your goal is here, but you should never pass your secrets around willy nilly. However, if you want to, you may have to pass them as args from where you are calling the task. Like so:

**task.py**

```
@shared_task()
def task_mytask(my_secret_env, my_secret_setting):
    ...
```

**views.py**

```
task_mytask.apply_async(args=[my_secret_env, my_secret_setting])
```

Also, you could try setting an environment variable and try calling that.

```
export MY_SETTING = 1234
```

Comment: I need to retrieve secret from an environment variable, directly or using settings.py as an intermediate (to centralize config values in one location). My shared task is not called from a view but triggered by a periodic task based on database settings.

Comment: Oh right, I see that now. Have you tried exporting your environment variables that you want passed through?
export MY_SECRET = 1234

Comment: Finally I duplicated Environment=MY_SECRET=1234 in both celery.service and celerybeat.service and now I can get the value of this environment variable directly using os.environ.get('MY_SECRET') within celery periodic task or celery shared task but it is kind of ugly.